Optimization to get unknown values using the absolute values of another vector
I have the matrix equation as follows:
$\begin{bmatrix}
a & a & a & a & a & a \\
b & b & b & b & b & b \\
c & c & c & c & c & c \\
e & e & e & e & e & e
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
d_1 \\
d_2 \\
d_3 \\
d_4 \\
d_5 \\
d_6
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
a & a & a & a \\
b & b & b & b \\
c & c & c & c \\
e & e & e & e
\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}
p_1 \\
p_2 \\
p_3 \\
p_4
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
y_3 \\
y_4
\end{bmatrix}  $
where $d$ is unknown but each value of $||d||^2 = 1$, and $d$ is randomly selected from a set of values example $(1, -1)$, $P$ and $y$ are known, how can I optimize the equation to find the coefficients $a, b, c, e$ subject to the constraint of $||d||^2 = 1$ and the above equality correct? Or Can that be solved directly?
The above equation is an example, the matrices can be much larger but with same form as mentioned above.

Optimize in what sense?

@HyperbolicPDEfriend For example optimization of unknown values we want to calculate $a, b, c, d, e, f$ subject to have $||d||^2 = 1$. Actually, I am asking how can we deal with it

@user1551 , it's updated. Thank you

The equation can be rewritten as
$$
\left(\sum_id_i+\sum_jp_j\right)\pmatrix{a\ b\ c\ e}=\pmatrix{y_1\ y_2\ y_3\ y_4}.
$$
The equation is not solvable if $\sum_id_i+\sum_jp_j=0$ and $y\ne0$. If $\sum_id_i+\sum_jp_j$ is nonzero, it is solved by
$$
\pmatrix{a\ b\ c\ e}=\left(\sum_id_i+\sum_jp_j\right)^{-1}\pmatrix{y_1\ y_2\ y_3\ y_4}.
$$
If $\sum_id_i+\sum_jp_j=0$ and $y=0$, any $a,b,c,e$ will do.

@user1551 but $d_i$ is unknown, we know that $||d_i||^2 = 1$.
